# Is it safe to downgrade git version for a particular repository?

Tags: git

I work on a git repository that I created using git 2.10 six months ago and I work on it actively. This particular version (git 2.10) is installed locally and used only for this repo.

I use Ubuntu 16.04, which has git 2.7.
I've decided to simplify and switch to use Ubuntu-provided git 2.7.

Is it safe to downgrade from git 2.10 to 2.7?

Comment: If unsure, you could use the older git version to `clone` the repo.

Comment: But there are only a handful of features like `git worktree` that shouldn't work in sufficiently old versions.

Comment: @o11c, actually `git worktree` was the reason I use self-compiled `git` 2.10:
 worktrees are supported only on `git 2.5+` and I had Ubuntu 14.04 before, which had some older version of `git`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it must be safe. 
The way git store the data in the repository has not changed since the first versions (or very lightly) because it is very simple and elegant.

So, no problem. 
You will just loose some features and bug fixes...

In our team, CI  servers still use git in 1.9.5 (for lack of time to upgrade) while developers use a range from 2 to the last version.